# How to count number of "//" commented lines in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to count the number of "//" commented lines in a file, NOT total number of comments. 
I tried using strstr() function to check if the string "//" is in the string line, but it is counting every line?

```
case(3) :

    while (fgets(line, 300, q)){

    if (strstr(line, "//") == NULL) CommentedRows++;

    }
```

I also tried with strchr() to look for the first occurrence of '/' and then check if the next symbol is '/', but the result is always 0?

Comment: Did you mean `if (strstr(line, "//")) CommentedRows++;` ??

Comment: FYI -- Your code will also match `printf("//");` Not sure if that's a problem for you.

Comment: `if(strstr(line, "//") != NULL)` that is what I think should be the code

Comment: I thought that if ==NULL then match is found?

Comment: Your code fails on itself.

Comment: If != NULL again it's always 0

Comment: As in, even if it did what you want it to do, it would still pick up the line where it looks for the "//".

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). Perhaps the bug is elsewhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`strstr()`'s documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html):

> These functions return a pointer to the beginning of the substring, or NULL if the substring is not found.

So you should do

```
if (strstr(line, "//") != NULL) 
{
  CommentedRows++;
}
```

or even shorter

```
if (strstr(line, "//")) 
{
  CommentedRows++;
}
```

However this just tells you that `line` contains the C-"string" `"//"` somewhere, wether this is to be interpreted as a C++/C99 comment is another story though.

Comment: Sir i think there should be check that these 2 must be the first 2 char's

Comment: @Gopi: `//` can start a comment even if they are not the first chars, for example  like in  this line ..... `std::cout << std::endl; // output blank line`

Comment: if (strstr(line, "//")) 
{
  CommentedRows++;
} results 0 evry time

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes I meant this will not give proper count of number of comments there has to be some guidelines in the OP's code which says comment should be in a separate line else you might end up fetching `//` which is part of some valid C statement

Comment: @S.F.R.PARTIZAN: No, it doesn't. Why do you think it does?

Comment: @alk when i compile it, it says: Lines with "//" are: 0

Comment: Also, I don't care if "//" is something else than a comment (like a valid C statement)

Answer (score 3):

Just because a line has // on it does not mean is has a comment, because // might be part of a string, part of another comment or even part of an xmldoc comment.

Assuming you want to count the lines that are 'fully commented', ie, they start with the comment, possibly having optional whitespace chars before it, then this might be a solution:

```cpp
bool IsFullyCommentedLine(char* line)
{
    // For each character in the line
    for (int i = 0; line[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        char c = line[i];

        // If it is a / followed by another /, we consider 
        // the line to be fully commented
        if (c == '/' && line[i + 1] == '/')
        {
            return true;
        }

        // If we find anything other than whitespace, 
        // we consider the line to not be fully commented
        else if (c != ' ' && c != '\t')
        {
            break;
        }

        // As long as we get here we have whitespaces at the
        // beginning of the line, so we keep looking...
    }

    return false;
}

int CountFullyCommentedLines(FILE* file)
{
    char buffer[1024];

    int commentCount = 0;
    while (char* line = fgets(buffer, 1024, file))
    {
        if (IsFullyCommentedLine(line))
            commentCount++;
    }

    return commentCount;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        printf("Number of fully commented lines, ie the ones that start with optional whitespace/tabs and //:\r\n");
        printf("%i\r\n", CountFullyCommentedLines(file));
        fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Again, this assumes you don't want to count comments that start in the middle of the line, just the ones that comment the entire line.

Comment: A good example of this is the program the OP is trying to write.

Comment: I don't care if "//" is something else than a comment